# Using res.send() outside of Routes file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm very new to Node JS and Express, so apologies if this question is all over the place.

In one my routes, I'm calling a function in a separate module:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var imgur = require('../helpers/imgur.js');

router.get('/imagesearch/:query', function(req, res) {

    imgur.search('cats', '2');

});

module.exports = router;
```

The Imgur helper file currently looks like this:

```
const https = require('https');

module.exports = {
    search : function(query, pagination) {
        var options = {
            host: 'api.imgur.com',
            path: '/3/gallery/search/hot/' + pagination + '?q=' + query,
            port: 443,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Authorization' : 'Client-ID ' + process.env.API_KEY}
        };

        var callback = function(res) {
            var str = '';

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                var result = JSON.parse(str);
                result = result.data;

                var finalResult = [];

                for(var key in result) {
                    url = result[key].link;
                    title = result[key].title;
                    points = result[key].points;

                    var temp = {url: url, title: title, points: points};

                    finalResult.push(temp);
                }

                return finalResult;
            });
        };

        var req = https.request(options, callback);

        req.end();

        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
    }
};
```

The aim is to convert the finalResult variable to JSON and serve it via res.send, much like an API would.

As you can see, I've tried to return data from the function, but I don't think is very in tune with how Node works. I've tried using res.send and even res.render, but both of these return "X is not a function".

I know I need to use a callback somehow, but at this point I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `res` object into your `search` function and then you can call `res.send()` from within that function.

Declare it as an argument:

```
search : function(res, query, pagination) {
```

Pass it in:

```
router.get('/imagesearch/:query', function(req, res) {
    imgur.search(res, 'cats', '2');
});
```

Then, from within the implementation of your `search` function, you can call `res.send(...)` wherever you want to.

---

Or, you could have the `search` function return a promise that you would resolve with the result when you have the async result and then your router could use that promise to obtain the result.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this in a nice way. You should be handling the response where you call the function, not passing it to search as some would suggest:

### 1. Send a callback into search

```
imgur.search('cats', '2', function (data) {
    res.send(data) // call callback with data and send or whatever you want
});
```

Then in search:

```
function search(query, pagination, cb) {
    // Do stuff
    cb(null, data);
}
```

### 2. Use promises

```
imgur
    .search('cats', 2)
    .then(function (data) {
        res.send(data) // Or whatever
    })
```

To do 2. you need to return a promise from the search function (my example is using bluebird)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
function search(query, pagination) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Do stuff
        return resolve(data);
    }
}
```